# How to download 2 tables to excel sheet using PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I have a PHP code to download one mysql table to excel sheet.what i want to do is download 2 tables in to same excel sheet.those tables are should be in different excel worksheet.please help me.

this code work fine.it's download one table.

```
<?php

ob_start();
session_start();
include('dbconnection.php');
$usr = $_SESSION['fname'];

header('Content-Type: text/csv');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment;filename=exported-data.csv');

$select_table = mysql_query("select * from regfarmer WHERE ffname='$usr'");

$rows = mysql_fetch_assoc($select_table);

if ($rows) {
    getcsv(array_keys($rows));
}
while ($rows) {
    getcsv($rows);
    $rows = mysql_fetch_assoc($select_table);
}

function getcsv($no_of_field_names) {
    $separate = '';

    foreach ($no_of_field_names as $field_name) {
        if (preg_match('/\\r|\\n|,|"/', $field_name)) {
            $field_name = '' . str_replace('', $field_name) . '';
        }
        echo $separate . $field_name;

        $separate = ',';
    }

    echo "\r\n";
}
?>
```

Comment: CSV is a simple format that doesn't support multiple worksheets... for multiple worksheets, you need to use a proper spreadsheet format such as OfficeOpenXML, BIFF, Gnumeric or OASIS

Answer (score 0):

i've found a code for split to excel sheet.Now how i integrate mysql table selection for this code?

```
<?php
require_once 'PHPExcel.php';
require_once 'PHPExcel/IOFactory.php';

// Create new PHPExcel object
$objPHPExcel = new PHPExcel();

// Create a first sheet, representing sales data
$objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0);
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('A1', 'Something');

// Rename sheet
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setTitle('Name of Sheet 1');

// Create a new worksheet, after the default sheet
$objPHPExcel->createSheet();

// Add some data to the second sheet, resembling some different data types
$objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(1);
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('A1', 'More data');

// Rename 2nd sheet
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setTitle('Second sheet');

// Redirect output to a client’s web browser (Excel5)
header('Content-Type: application/vnd.ms-excel');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment;filename="name_of_file.xls"');
header('Cache-Control: max-age=0');
$objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPExcel, 'Excel5');
$objWriter->save('php://output');
?>
```